# How to customize validation error message given by text-danger?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dropdown list on one of my pages in my MVC .NET Core project that I want to customise the default validation text for.

```
<select asp-for="ProductID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductID">
    <option value="">--Select Product --</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="ProductID" class="text-danger" />
```

The standard validation error message given is "The Product ID field is required".  I want to change this to something else.

I have tried using this

```
 <span asp-validation-for="ProductID" class="text-danger">Please enter a product</span>
```

But the error message displays when the page loads instead of when the button is clicked

What is the appropriate way to customise validation text?

Comment: show us your view model

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's normally done in the ViewModel you want to return to the Controller:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your elegant error message goes here")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So the only way to customize the error message is if I use a ViewModel?  I didn't plan on creating a ViewModel just for this purpose.

Comment: @crazyPen It's not really common to use ASP.NET MVC without ViewModels. Why wouldn't you use them? (ViewModel in the sense of models that the View uses)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. I am new to dotnet and didn't realise how important ViewModels are

Answer (score 4):

If you do not require ViewModel then you can use the following,

Add "data-val-required" for message

Then "data-valmsg-replace" will display the same

Comment: This seems to be a neater approach to the original question than coding it into the model. This page goes into its workings: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/