# How to connect asp-validation-for to my new error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made new error message in my controller like that

```
        if (!viewModel.Appointment.isConfirmed) ;
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "You haven't confirmed in checkbox!");
        }
```

How can I connect span with asp-validation-for only to this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ModelState.AddModelError` in your code and name for key:

Controller:

```
if (!viewModel.Appointment.isConfirmed)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("YourErrorName", "You haven't confirmed in checkbox!");
        }
```

View:

```
<span> @Html.ValidationMessage("YourErrorName") </span>
```

Or if you like use asp-validation-for, let check it in [How to customize validation error message given by text-danger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435891/how-to-customize-validation-error-message-given-by-text-danger)

Comment: Also need to specify `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in the cshtml file

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thanks! At first I did an alert using js, but this is a way better solution